# Sonarqube ghost projects in issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am currently configuring a sonarqube instance with version of 5.1 and after several analyzes there are ghost projects appearing in issues tab on main page. Currently there is only one project that is being analyzed with same identifier and when i check database for those projects there is only one project and all issues in the corresponding table has same project_uuid. But the problem arises when i want to list all issues related to every project on server. On left side when i choose *Project* filter there should be one project but there are unnamed projects appear and when i choose an issue within a ghost project sonarqube gives error with message "*Parameter 'uuid' is missing*". when i check the URL for the uuid of the ghost project, i could not find any trace for that uuid in database either. Is there a way to remove these ghost projects or i am running sonar-runner with a wrong configuration?

Edit - config:

```
sonar.projectKey=x
sonar.projectName=x
sonar.projectVersion=1.0 
sonar.modules=a,b,c
a.sonar.projectBaseDir=modules/a
b.sonar.projectBaseDir=modules/b
c.sonar.projectBaseDir=modules/c
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=test
sonar.java.binaries=../**/classes/production,../**/classes/test
sonar.java.libraries=../../libraries/repository
sonar.junit.reportsPath=junit/
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reporthPath=coverage/jacoco.exec
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: What's your sonar-runner.properties file look like for the project? Also you can [delete projects](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration) if you're logged in as Admin by clicking on the Project then Settings > Deletion

Comment: Deleting is not an option since there is only single project listed there but i suspect it could be related with Jenkins plugin which triggers sonar-runner with properties provided over the plugin. Compiling, testing and coverage reports are results of an ant build task and i only use the generated reports of jacoco and junit to display metrics. By the way its configured as a multi module project and i set projectBaseDir for each module.

Comment: Have you tried the global administration "Bulk Deletion" page, where you can click on "Ghosts" to remove ghost projects?

Comment: There is only 1 project in Bulk deletion, those projects appear only in filters where issues listed and because of this there are more issues in "My Unresolved Issues" widget than it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are showing up on issues tab only, it seems like an issue with indexing, somehow the search index seems to be corrupted. You can try to delete the ES index and see if it fixes the issue for you. The ES index is stored in `<sonar-install-dir>/data/es` folder.